# Identification of fibre-to-LED circular connector (for car LED lights)

Tags: identification, connector, optical-fibre

I have purchased some car LED lights for my vehicle, but the optic cable is too short. I need to buy some sort of extension and need to know what this piece on the right is called (see image below). I pop it out for easy viewing but when pulled back in the left side in my hand connects with the right.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a LED on a tiny custom PCB.